# Confused on my JavaScript code when calling a URL and not sure if I need an Ajax call

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a .html file.

In the file, there is a link like this:

```
<a href="https://www.someOtherWebsite.com/" onclick="clicked('https://www.MyWebsite.com/send_emai.php?subject=hello&body=test')">Some text</a>
```

The clicked is supposedly calling a JavaScript function which for now is in the header of the same file and looks like this (I got pieces of it from different places online):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function clicked(url) {
   // your server call
   fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(json => console.log(json))
   // open the link in new tab
   window.open(url);
 }
 </script>
```

I really just need to navigate to the URL in the href, but hit this URL which sends me an email about it:

```
https://www.MyWebsite.com/send_emai.php?subject=hello&body=test
```

And don't need this function to return. Do I still need Ajax? And is this code correct or am I missing some syntax? I last used JavaScript and Axax 10 years ago so this is a bit of a struggle :)

Thanks!

Comment: "hit that URL" - which one? you have three different ones mentioned in your code

Comment: @JaromandaX This URL from onClicked: https://www.MyWebsite.com/send_emai.php?subject=hello&body=test'

Comment: your code is most likely going to navigate to the `href` url, not the one you pass to clicked function - I may be wrong, what do you see is happening when you click the link? and why would you have a href that is never going to be navigated to? Also, the fetch may or may not occur, if the fetch does occur, it's unlikely that any of the `.then` will occur, since you'll navigate to a new page

Comment: I do want it to navigate to the href URL. But I need it to hit that other url so it sends me an email about it.

Comment: and also open a new tab? the confusion (for me) is 3 completely unrelated URLS, and your code doesn't make any connection between them

Comment: No, I don't need to open a new tab - just need to hit that url https://www.MyWebsite.com/send_emai.php? and that's it.

Comment: oh, it's your code that has the comment `open the link in new tab` - I guess I must be reading something in your code that you don't want to happen?

Answer (score 0):

What if you hit the url that sends the email first, then navigate away?

I don't know exactly how fetch works, but you could try something like this:

```html
<a onclick="clicked('https://www.someOtherWebsite.com/')">Some text</a>
<script>
 function clicked(url) {
   // your server call
   fetch('https://www.MyWebsite.com/send_emai.php?subject=hello&body=test')
   .then(() => {window.location.href = url});
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you - should I put the script right there below the HTM link or in my header?

Comment: Either one should work. You should prefer `<head>` for scripts that get used for multiple buttons.